# comparing the datefield to today and changing the integerfield automatically every day

Tags: python, django

I'm making a website using django.

```
class Member(models.Model):
      ...
      end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)))
      Membership_status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1) # 1 = active, 0=deactivate, 2=refund
```

What I want to do is comparing the end_date field to today.date every 1.a.m. and if today's day < end_date,  Membership_status field is changed to 0 automatically.

I heard I should use django-kronos(https://github.com/jgorset/django-kronos). 
But I can't understand the using method.

Is there anyone can tell me details how I implement what I want?

Any help will be very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to have a Membership_status field?  You'll be duplicating information, which tends to lead to inconsistency.Instead you could just check whether `end_date` is in the past when you want to know if the status has expired (I'd suggest adding `db_index=True` to `end_date` for this purpose so you can efficiently query for the status of all members at once).

Comment: @JohnCarter Thanks for your comments, but what does 'db_index=True'  mean? I want to check the Member's status (active, expired, refund).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-index if you want to also track refunded as well, you could use a refunded_at datetime column (with default=None)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not an answer to your original query, but merely a suggestion for your future,

Never pass a function call into your field defaults. If you did, the function would be evaluated at the time of your migrations. If you look into the migration files you can see for sure. Instead wrap it in a function and pass that as a callable.

Eg:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def TODAY():
    return timezone.now().date()

def NEXT_MONTH_DAY():
    return TODAY() + timedelta(days=30)
```

Now, in your models,

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ...
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=NEXT_MONTH_DAY)
```

This way the function `NEXT_MONTH_DAY` is called whenever an instance of `Member` is created.

**EDIT**:

For your original query, I haven't tested the code, but I suppose you are looking for maybe something like this,

```
import kronos

@kronos.register('0 1 * * *')
def the_task():
    for member in Member.objects.all():
        if TODAY() == member.end_date:
            member.Membership_status = 0
            member.save()
```

Comment: No, it'd result in unwanted changes.

Comment: Member.objects.filter(end_date__lte=TODAY()).update(membership_status=0‌​)

Comment: `__lte` equivalent to "less than or equal to" so, this query would also be wrong and inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How the kronos method implements automatically every midnight?? ( I just installed kronos and wrote the 'kronos' in installed app and I made cron.py)

Comment: I'm afraid the working of cron jobs are out of my knowledge. You may need to look in their documentations or such tutorials. I happen to stumble on just an example and wrote this code, just to give you an idea.